# Unable to read large file of Network shared folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files

I am trying to read the text file to check whether all the rows has same number of columns or not. In local code its working fine but on the Network shared folder (has permission as Everyone) it is working only for small size (5mb) of file and when I am selecting 10 MB or 500 MB file same code is not working (Not working means, it takes some time but after few minutes page gets refresh, that's it). It is not giving any error or showing any message. Below is the code to read the file and get the columns count

```
LinesLst = File.ReadLines(_fileName, Encoding.UTF8)
    .Select((line, index) =>
        {
            var count = line.Split(Delimiter).Length;
            if (NumberOfColumns < 0)
                NumberOfColumns = count;

            return new
            {
                line = line,
                count = count,
                index = index
            };
        })
    .Where(colCount => colCount.count != NumberOfColumns)
    .Select(colCount => colCount.line).ToList();
```

Comment: "It is not giving any error or showing any message" - that is really unlikely. If you happen to use Windows there would be errors in event log... Otherwise use some logging library to capture and loge errors.

Comment: is there anyway to improve the performance of the code, so the process will be faster as file is big file (500 MB)

Comment: If there is no error message, how do you know it's not working? Are you sure you're not running out of memory? It'd be difficult to make a huge performance improvement because just reading the file is going to be the major bottleneck.

Comment: I'm going to second @AlexeiLevenkov, you need some more profiling on this code, and a better description on this question of *how* it isn't working.

Comment: @Rocky (not exactly serious comment) it is very easy to make code that *does not work* faster - just skip all the code and you get the same result. On a bit more serious note - stream result out without converting to list or any other local structure...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Is it simply not responding?  If there are no exceptions, perhaps the `ToList()` call is causing you to wait longer than you expect--particularly for network shares.  What happens if you simply iterate over the items?

Comment: Not working means, it takes some time but after few minutes page gets refresh that too only on selecting shared folder file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added  AsyncPostBackTimeout="36000" which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have `OutOfMemoryException` on large file. The fact is that are created many objects in the code on each iteration: the string array by `line.Split` and an anonymous object. Meanwhile, the anonymous object in fact is not needed. I would rewrote the code as so:

```
LinesLst = File.ReadLines(_fileName, Encoding.UTF8)
    .Where(line =>
    {
        var count = line.Split(Delimiter).Length;
        if (NumberOfColumns < 0)
            NumberOfColumns = count;

        return count != NumberOfColumns;
    })
    .ToList();
```

In addition, you can try to get rid of the creation of the string array when you call the `line.Split`. Try to replace the string

```
var count = line.Split(Delimiter).Length;
```

to the string

```
// Assume that Delimiter is char[]
var count = line.Count(c => Delimiter.Contains(c)) + 1;

// Assume that Delimiter is char
var count = line.Count(c => Delimiter == c) + 1;
```